# Exit method using Action that uses lambda expression

Tags: vb.net, lambda

Let's say I have this method:

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim ac As Action = Sub()
                           Console.WriteLine("Aborting")
                           Exit Sub ' This will exit the Action not the caller method.
                       End Sub
    Console.WriteLine("1")
    ac()
    Console.WriteLine("2")
    Console.WriteLine("3")
    Console.WriteLine("4")
End Sub
```

I'm trying to use the `Action` to exit the method that calls it (`Foo`). Obviously, calling `Exit Sub` from inside the lambda expression will exit the action itself not the caller method.

So, is there a way to trigger `Exit Sub` of `Foo` from inside the Action's lambda expression?

---

**Why am I trying to do this?**

Well, I have a `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` event where I need to trigger the same action multiple times and I don't want to repeat myself. The normal approach is to create a separate method with all the repeated code and call the method when/where needed. Well, I can't do that because some of the "repeated code" can't be called from a separate method (e.g. `e.Result = False` & `Exit Sub`). That's why I thought of using an `Action` which might not be the right approach.

So is there any other way to handle this?

---

**Edit (2)**

Basically, I'm trying to do the following:

```
    If condition1 Then Abort()
    If condition2 Then Abort()
    If condition3 Then Abort()
```

Instead of:

```
    If condition1 Then 
        Abort()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If condition2 Then 
        Abort()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If condition3 Then 
        Abort()
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Note: I can't combine `condition1`, `condition2`, and `condition3` together.

Comment: Ask yourself this. If you had two regular methods with one calling the other, would you expect the second method to be able to force the first one to return?  Of course not, so why would you be able to in this case?  Just like with a regular method, the Lambda would have to set a variable that the calling method could then test and then return if it's a particular value.

Comment: Words of wisdom from the pros. @jmcilhinney, can I ask an off-topic question? Does you reps rollbacked? It was way more as I remembered.

Comment: @CrushSundae, not that I'm aware of. Maybe you're thinking of another site.

Comment: @jmcilhinney You're right. I added more info to the question because it's possible to be an xy problem and I'm using the wrong approach.

Comment: Ahh right! `VBForums` I guess? Sorry for being off-topic. ;p

Comment: Instead of trying to set `e.Result` to a value from within a `Sub`, why not use a `Function` that returns a `bool` that the caller can then assign to `e.Result`? Alternatively, pass `e` in as an argument and then the parameter's `Result` property can be set within the method.

Comment: @jmcilhinney You mean passing `e.Result` by reference to another method? Yes, it's a good point. But `e.Result` problem is already fixed using the `Action`. Now what about `Exit Sub`? :D Is there a way to not repeat this?

Comment: No, I don't mean that.  I mean what I said.  I said pass `e`.  I meant pass `e`.  Write a regular method with a parameter of type `DoWorkEventArgs` or whatever it is and then pass in `e`.  Inside that method, you would set the `Result` property on that parameter.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sorry for the mix-up. I think passing `e` then changing `Result` will do the same thing as passing `e.Result` and changing it. Anyways, that's still not the main issue here.

Comment: The main issue is that what you're trying to do is impossible. The only way to return from or exit a method is with a `Return` or `Exit` statement in that method. As I said, you can set a variable in another method and then test that variable to decide whether to return or exit but that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do with `If condition1 Then Abort()` is not the correct approach. Still you want to do the same here is a work around. You can even use try-catch block one level up i.e. outside Foo(). If you want to completely exit the Foo() but it depends on your logic.

```
Sub Foo()
    Const EXCP_MSSG_ABORT As String = "Aborting-101"
    Try
        Dim ac As Action = Sub()
                               Console.WriteLine("Aborting")
                               Throw New Exception(EXCP_MSSG_ABORT)
                           End Sub
        Console.WriteLine("1")
        ac()
        Console.WriteLine("2")
        Console.WriteLine("3")
        Console.WriteLine("4")
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Just ignore the exception and exit OR you want to be specific then check the message and exit
        'If ex.Message = EXCP_MSSG_ABORT Then
        '    Console.WriteLine("Exited from Action")
        'End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Lol. It's a nice & funny workaround. I might not use it now. But it does exactly what I asked for, so it's a correct answer. Thanks mate :)